# Can Ruby subclass instance variables _overwrite_ the superclass's (same name)?

Tags: ruby, inheritance, subclass, instance-variables, superclass

In the Chapter 7.3.5 "Inheritance and Instance Variables" of the book "the ruby programing language" says :

> Because instance variables have nothing to do with
>   inheritance, it follows that an instance variable used by a subclass cannot “shadow” an
>   instance variable in the superclass. If a subclass uses an instance variable with the same
>   name as a variable used by one of its ancestors, it will **overwrite** the value of its >ancestor’s
>   variable. This can be done intentionally, to alter the behavior of the ancestor, or it can
>   be done inadvertently. In the latter case, it is almost certain to cause bugs. As with the
>   inheritance of private methods described earlier, this is another reason why it is only
>   safe  to  extend  Ruby  classes  when  you  are  familiar  with  (and  in  control  of)  the
>   implementation of the superclass.

I had made my own test , but seems instance variables from subclass does NOT affect the superclass

my Ruby version

```
bob@bob-ruby:~$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [i686-linux]
bob@bob-ruby:~$
```

Below is the code

```
class Point
   attr_accessor :x,:y
   def initialize(x,y)
     @x,@y=x,y
   end
end

class Point3D < Point
   attr_accessor :x,:y,:z
   def initialize(x,y,z)
     @x=x
     @y=y
     @z=z
   end
end

irb(main):052:0> p=Point.new(1,2)
=> #<Point:0x87e8968 @x=1, @y=2>
irb(main):053:0> q=Point3D.new(4,5,6)
=> #<Point3D:0x87e423c @x=4, @y=5, @z=6>
irb(main):054:0> q.x
=> 4
irb(main):055:0> p.x
=> 1
irb(main):056:0>
```

Comment: Umm, these are "instance" variables, and here you have 2 separate instances of 2 classes, what did you expect?

Comment: Yes , this is what I'm confusing . Because the book says it will _overwrite_ the value of the superclass , is the book wrong ?

Comment: @ailms No, you're wrong in thinking that when you have two instances of a class that setting an instance variable in one will affect the other. The book is saying if you set the value in the superclass (like in the ctor) *then* set it in the subclass, the subclass's value wins.

Comment: @Dave Newton : I'm not thinking have two instances of a _same_ class. I had 2 instances of two different classes . The book sayes it will **_alter_** the behavior of superclass , but if the instance  variables from subclass has no relationship with the one from superclass , how **CAN** it **'alter the behavior'** and **cause bugs** ?

Comment: @ailms Moved comment to answer for space and formatting reasons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book (emphasis and addition mine):

> If a **subclass** uses an **instance** variable with the same name as a[n instance] variable used by one of its ancestors, it will overwrite the value of its ancestor’s variable.

I know you don't have two instances of the same class; we're specifically discussing inheritance.

When a subclass uses an instance variable with the same name as an instance variable used by the superclass, there's a single instance variable. If the subclass changes the value of that instance variable, and the superclass accesses it, it gets the value set by the subclass.

When a subclass is instantiated, it acts "as-if" it's *also* an instance of the superclass. The way Ruby is implemented means that if the superclass has an instance variable `@foo`, the subclass can access it. This makes a distinction between the subclass's `@foo` and the superclass's `@foo` meaningless.

This is how subclasses may alter superclass behavior: by setting a value the superclass might use. If a subclass sets `@foo = 42`, and a superclass method accesses `@foo`, it sees `42`. This may or may not be intended, hence the warning. It can lead to spectacularly frustrating debugging sessions.

```ruby
class MyStack
  def initialize
    @my_array = []
  end

  def push(item)
    @my_array << item
  end
end

# Stack class that keeps a list 
# of every item ever pushed.
class TrackingStack < MyStack
  def initialize
    super
    @my_array = []
  end

  def push(item)
    super
    @my_array << item
  end

  def all_items_ever_pushed
    @my_array
  end
end
```

`TrackingStack` introduces a bug, because it inadvertently used the same name as the superclass's array used to hold the stack contents. If you weren't familiar with the superclass's implementation, this would cause confusion and bugs until you dug deeply enough to understand where the unintended behavior came from.

An instance of the superclass is just that: an *instance* of the superclass, and it's meaningless to talk about how an *instance* of the *subclass* will affect it, because they're completely unrelated.

Here's a rephrasing:

> Subclassing can be risky when you don't control, or are unfamiliar with, the superclass implementation. One reason is because the introduction of an instance variable in the subclass may overwrite the value of a superclass instance variable, leading to unintended behavior.

Comment: why is a single instance variable? I don't understand , you mean the @x,@y in subclass "Point3D" is the same instance variable in superclass "Point"? can you make some code in the answer ? tks

Comment: @ailms That's precisely the (ahem) point: let's say `Point3D` did some sort of transform on `@x` and `@y` because it's in 3D. If `Point` had behavior that didn't expect that transform, `Point`'s behavior would change in a potentially undesired way. I added a more-transparent example.

Comment: I think I got you . the word 'alter the behavior' means that when the 'super' method in subclass access the instance variable ,it will see the value from subclass instance , not the value of instance variable of superclass .  does it right ?

   p.s  : the second class seems like without "< MyStack"

Comment: I run the code (with <MyStack added) , and make two instance : "s" for "MyStack" , "t" for TackingStack . 
And I run s.push("123"),  it looks right . And then I run t.push("456") , it returns the ["456","456"], not the  ["456"].
Then I make two different changes , both of them show me the correct result
   1) changed the "my_array" in TrackingStack into "my_sub_array" 
   2) remove 'super' method  from "push" method in TrackingStack.
The first change is obviously right , the second change means that 'super' took the "456" and push it to the array of t , not "123" from s

Comment: @ailms It might look right, until you have a `pop` that modifies `@my_array` in the superclass `MyStack`. To fix the implementation you need a different array in `TrackingStack`. You need `super` in `push` in order to share the superclass's behavior, which is the point of subclassing.

Comment: I add the pop code ("@my_array.pop")  to the superclass on your code and run

   s.push("123")  return ["123"]

   t.push("456") return ["456","456"]

   s.pop return ["123"]

   it seems ok . "@my_array" of s and "@my_array" of t do NOT affect each other .

   I can't see the problem you said

Comment: @ailms I know you can't, but that's weird, because if you didn't push "456" twice, why is it in the array twice? Because it's added twice: once by TrackingStack's push, and once by MyStack's push. They absolutely *do* "affect" each other: **they're the same array**.

Comment: @ailms In addition, *because* they're the same array, the superclass will be popping values meant to be persisted as a tracked push by the subclass.

Comment: I make another test , and see that although the superclass create the "@my_array" first , but in the initialize method of subclass , the assign expression cause to create another new "@my_array" with different object_id . 
**1) why you said the are the same array?** .
**2) why the push in superclass sees the instance variable created by subclass ?** 
**3) the super method in subclass runs in the context of subclass or superclass?**
Is that because the instance variable are **ALWAYS** resolved in the context of self , so super in subclass take TrackingStack instance object as 'self' ?

Comment: @ailms ... (1) `@my_array` is the same reference in both classes; the subclass clobbers the superclass's array. (2) Because `@my_array` is the same variable: this is the whole point of the discussion we've been having, and the reason for the warning in the book. (3) I really don't think you're grasping the nature of OOP: if you instantiate an instance of `TrackingStack` there's only one instance of a class. It's a `TrackingStack` that includes functionality of its superclass.

Comment: sorry,My first time to learn OOP and the time lag .
Do you mean : the `super` method WON't create any superclass intance obj or context , it just include the code of it's superclass , there's only a single obj ,no superclass instance obj generated, like source script.sh in Bash . From this point , the @my_array is the same for both class. But I still think that the superclass init method create the `@my_array` first , then by the assignment , the subclass re-create it , because the objecvt id changed (add `print @my_array.object_id` in initialized method of both class after the assignment )

Comment: another two question  1): `super` cuase method lookup . But what is the **receiver** of the superclass's method , the subclass instance obj?  2) does this limit decrease the 'magic' of Ruby heavily ? or bring obviously inconvenient to metaprogramming ? Because I can't do the check all the time to ensure I won't make this mistake.

Comment: @ailms It's something to be aware of, and it can lead to surprising behavior. It's not directly related to metaprogramming; the risks are the same.

Answer (score 1):

Instance variables belong to instances, not to classes. The whole idea of "inheritance" doesn't even make sense there, inheritance only applies to classes.

Comment: Yes , this is what I'm confusing . Because the book says it will _overwrite_ the value of the superclass , is the book wrong ? or do I missunderstood anything ?

Comment: Probably not the best time to start talking about class instance variables ;)